# Etymology of '괜찮다'

Tags: etymology, adjective

The adjective '[괜찮다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=3858300)' means:

> 형용사 (adjective)
>
> 별로 나쁘지 않고 보통 이상이다. Not bad and above average.

When you look at the adjective '[편찮다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=40429800)', you can know it is from another adjective '[편하다](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=40379201)' as '편찮다' is a contracted from of '편치 않다', which is again short for '편하지 않다'.

What is the etymology of '괜찮다'?

Comment: I searched on the web for the word 괜하다 in 네이버 국어사전, and it says: 아무 까닭이나 실속이 없다, and an antonym is  공연하다. Maybe 괜찮다 came from 괜치 않다? I am not sure.

Answer (score 6):

From Naver's online dictionary:

> 어원 : ←괜 [＜空然] +하-+-지+아니-+하-

Seems to be derived from 괜하지 않다

Also, [from here](http://koreanstudies1991.blogspot.kr/2015/08/and.html):

> -찮다 is simply a contraction of -치 (cf. "-지 않다") + 않다 (않다 -> 아니하다 "to
>   not be"). "괜" is a contracted form of the noun 관계 (關係) "relation,
>   connection." Written out, the word's entire original form would be:
>   "관계하지 아니하다," meaning "to not be concerned/ relevant/ matter." Hence
>   the meaning "it is okay/ alright" (i.e. "it does not matter, it is of
>   no concern").