# Can I use 찮다 to express 지 않다

Tags: grammar, etymology, abbreviated

I refer to this question: 
[Etymology of '괜찮다'](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/625/etymology-of-%EA%B4%9C%EC%B0%AE%EB%8B%A4)

So words like 귀찮다, 괜찮다, or 편찮다 are actually just the shortened form of 귀하지 않다, 괜하지 않다 and 편하지 않다. And the general rule is, 찮다 is the shortened form of 하지 않다.

Here the question comes: can I shortened any 하다 words which exist in the form 하지 않다 into 찮다, like these:

만족하지 않다 --> 만족찮다

접하지 않다 --> 접찮다

I tend to think that it is reasonable to do so, however, I've never seen people use this shortened form. So can they be used? If yes, then in what situation will it be used?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean '귀하다', '괜하다', '만족하다' are all verbs? Where did you hear "접하지 않다"? What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shortening(지 않다 -> 잖다, 하지 않다 -> 찮다) is not general, and a lot of people don't even recognize that they're shortened forms. When shortening 귀하지 않다 to 귀찮다, it effectively altered the meaning(major usage) too. Almost nobody uses 귀찮다 to mean "not valuable", and 귀하지 않다 to mean "tiresome". Same with 괜찮다/괜하지 않다, 편찮다/편하지 않다, and 하찮다/하지 않다. Their usages and meanings have changed far from their original forms.

Other words with similar shortenings are:

> 점잖다 *gentle* (<젊지 않다, *not young*) 
>   적잖다 *more than a few* (<적지 않다, *not few*) 
>   같잖다 *ridiculous* (<같지 않다, *not like*)
>   되잖다 *no good* (<되지 않다)

Comment: If that's the case how can I identify the difference between 되잖다 and 되다 + 잖다(i.e. 되잖아), which may have different meanings.?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy 되잖다 is rarely used that way (as a predicate). It's almost always used in forms like 되잖은(attributive) and 되잖게(adverbial), as in 되잖은 소리, 되잖게 생떼를 쓰다, etc. So that distinction's usually not a problem.